# Selective rounding of a button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, graphics

I am working on a creating a button with selective corners rounded off. After searching on the web, I found some snippet which would round off all the corners of a button. But I need to round off only one or two corners of the button. This is how I want my buttons to look.

[image]

So, here I want Button A's top left corner to be rounded, B's top right, C's bottom left and D's bottom right.

Here is the code which I found to round off all the corners of a button.

```
Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath 
p.StartFigure() 
p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40), 180, 90) 
p.AddLine(40, 0, Button1.Width - 40, 0) 
p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - 40, 0, 40, 40), -90, 90) 
p.AddLine(Button1.Width, 40, Button1.Width, Button1.Height - 40) 
p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - 40, Button1.Height - 40, 40, 40), 0, 90) 
p.AddLine(Button1.Width - 40, Button1.Height, 40, Button1.Height) 
p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, Button1.Height - 40, 40, 40), 90, 90) 
p.CloseFigure() 
Button1.Region = New Region(p)
```

The problem is I don't have much idea about Graphics, so I can't tweak this to round off only a particular corner. Can you please help me understand the drawing logic or tweak this snippet to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub RoundCorners(ByVal leftTop As Boolean, ByVal rightTop As Boolean, ByVal rightBottom As Boolean, ByVal leftBottom As Boolean)
  Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath 
  p.StartFigure() 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, IIF(leftTop,40,1), IIF(leftTop,40,1)), 180, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - IIF(rightTop,40,1), 0, IIF(rightTop,40,1), IIF(rightTop,40,1)), -90, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - IIF(rightBottom,40,1), Button1.Height - IIF(rightBottom,40,1), IIF(rightBottom,40,1), IIF(rightBottom,40,1)), 0, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, Button1.Height - IIF(leftBottom,40,1), IIF(leftBottom,40,1), IIF(leftBottom,40,1)), 90, 90) 
  p.CloseFigure() 
  Button1.Region = New Region(p)
End Sub
```

Usage

```
RoundCorners(true,true,true,true) //Round all corners
RoundCorners(true,false,false,false) //Round left-top corner
```

### UPDATE

It's even better if we implement the `RoundCorners` method this way:

```
Public Sub RoundCorners(ByVal leftTop As Int32, ByVal rightTop As Int32, ByVal rightBottom As Int32, ByVal leftBottom As Int32)
  If leftTop <= 0 Then leftTop = 1
  If rightTop <= 0 Then rightTop = 1
  If rightBottom <= 0 Then rightBottom = 1
  If leftBottom <= 0 Then leftBottom = 1
  Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath 
  p.StartFigure() 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, leftTop, leftTop), 180, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - rightTop, 0, rightTop, rightTop), -90, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(Button1.Width - rightBottom, Button1.Height - rightBottom, rightBottom, rightBottom), 0, 90) 
  p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, Button1.Height - leftBottom, leftBottom, leftBottom), 90, 90) 
  p.CloseFigure() 
  Button1.Region = New Region(p)
End Sub
```

Usage

```
RoundCorners(40,40,40,40)   //Round all corners
RoundCorners(40,0,0,0)      //Round left-top corners
```

Comment: Getting runtime exception "Parameter is not valid." on turning off any corner. Works fine for all corners rounding.

Comment: @Harsh see my edit, we need some arc of at least `1 pixel in diameter`, it's almost nearly `0` so it should work for you. Otherwise you have to use a lot of `If` statements and maybe `AddPolygon`.

Comment: Life saver you are. Thanks a ton. This solution works perfectly. Can you please explain the logic a bit, so that i can control the related modifications. Suppose if i need to reduce the size of the arc.

Comment: @Harsh the logic is simple, each `AddArc` is corresponding to a corner, in this order `Left-Top, Right-Top, Right-Bottom, Left-Bottom`, the corner is `square` is in fact an `arc` of `0 pixel diameter` however it's not supported so we used `1 pixel diameter` instead. If you want to change the `arc diameter`, you can change the `40` in the code, remember the corresponding corners to the arcs in the order I pointed out.

Comment: @Harsh see my update for a better solution, with the new solution, you can also change the `corner diameter`.